# Inserting rows into a dataframe based on a vector that contains dates

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, zoo

This is what my dataframe looks like:

```
df <- read.table(text='

    Name      ActivityType     ActivityDate              
     John       Email            2014-01-01                              
     John       Webinar          2014-01-05                            
     John       Webinar          2014-01-20                                                       
     John       Email            2014-04-20                            
     Tom        Email            2014-01-01                              
     Tom       Webinar           2014-01-05                           
     Tom       Webinar           2014-01-20                                                        
     Tom       Email             2014-04-20                              

    ', header=T, row.names = NULL)
```

I have this vector x which contains different dates
`x<- c("2014-01-03","2014-01-25","2015-05-27")`. I want to insert rows in my original dataframe in a way that incorporates these dates in the x vector.This is what the output should look like:

```
    Name      ActivityType     ActivityDate              
     John       Email            2014-01-01
     John        NA              2014-01-03        
     John       Webinar          2014-01-05                            
     John       Webinar          2014-01-20
     John       NA               2014-01-25                                                       
     John       Email            2014-04-20
     John       NA               2015-05-27                            
     Tom        Email            2014-01-01
     Tom        NA               2014-01-03                              
     Tom       Webinar           2014-01-05                           
     Tom       Webinar           2014-01-20
     Tom       NA                2014-01-25                                                        
     Tom       Email             2014-04-20
     Tom       NA                2015-05-27
```

Sincerely appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) expand.grid** Using `expand.grid` create a data frame `adds` with the rows to be added and then use `rbind` to combine `df` and `adds` converting the `ActivityDate` column to `"Date"` class.  Then sort.  No packages are used.

```
adds <- expand.grid(Name = levels(df$Name), ActivityType = NA, ActivityDate = x)
both <- transform(rbind(df, adds), ActivityDate = as.Date(ActivityDate))

o <- with(both, order(Name, ActivityDate))
both[o, ]
```

giving:

```
   Name ActivityType ActivityDate
1  John        Email   2014-01-01
9  John         <NA>   2014-01-03
2  John      Webinar   2014-01-05
3  John      Webinar   2014-01-20
11 John         <NA>   2014-01-25
4  John        Email   2014-04-20
13 John         <NA>   2015-05-27
5   Tom        Email   2014-01-01
10  Tom         <NA>   2014-01-03
6   Tom      Webinar   2014-01-05
7   Tom      Webinar   2014-01-20
12  Tom         <NA>   2014-01-25
8   Tom        Email   2014-04-20
14  Tom         <NA>   2015-05-27
```

**2) sqldf**   This uploads adds and df to an sqlite data base which it creates on the fly, then it performs the sql query and downloads the result.  The computation occurs outside of R so it might work with your large data.

```
adds <- data.frame(Name = NA, ActivityDate = x)

library(sqldf)

sqldf("select * 
       from (select * 
             from df 
             union 
             select a.Name, NULL ActivityType, ActivityDate 
             from (select distinct Name from df) a 
             cross join adds b
            ) order by 1, 3"
      )
```

giving:

```
   Name ActivityType ActivityDate
1  John        Email   2014-01-01
2  John         <NA>   2014-01-03
3  John      Webinar   2014-01-05
4  John      Webinar   2014-01-20
5  John         <NA>   2014-01-25
6  John        Email   2014-04-20
7  John         <NA>   2015-05-27
8   Tom        Email   2014-01-01
9   Tom         <NA>   2014-01-03
10  Tom      Webinar   2014-01-05
11  Tom      Webinar   2014-01-20
12  Tom         <NA>   2014-01-25
13  Tom        Email   2014-04-20
14  Tom         <NA>   2015-05-27
```

Comment: Thanks you! worked like a charm. I just had to use format="%Y-%m-%d" as I changed the original post a little.

Comment: OK  I have revised it to correspond with the revised question.

Comment: My dataframe is almost 2.5 million rows. I am having memory allocation problem when extending solution to bigger data. I have 32GB of RAM and Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1439.3 Gb

Comment: I cant get past "adds". This is what I am doing in the real problem:adds <- expand.grid(ContactID = levels(df2$ContactID),SalesForce_Name = levels(df2$SalesForce_Name), ActivityType = NA, ActivityDate = x,SalesAmount=0,FundCode="",RT180=0,next180=0)

Comment: Have added second solution.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you've added one of the 'new' dates aginst each of the people, correct?

In which case you can turn your `x` into a `data.frame`, and merge/join it on

```
## original dataframe
df <- data.frame(Name = c(rep("John", 4), rep("Tom", 4)),
                 ActivityType = c("Email","Web","Web","Email","Email","Web","Web", "Email"),
                 ActivityDate = c("2014-01-01","2014-05-01","2014-20-01","2014-20-04","2014-01-01","2014-05-01","2014-20-01","2014-20-04"))

## Turning x into a dataframe.
x <- data.frame(ActivityDate = rep(c("2014-01-03","2014-01-25","2015-05-27"), 2),
                Name = rep(c("John","Tom"), 3))

merge(df, x, by=c("Name", "ActivityDate"), all=T)

#    Name ActivityDate ActivityType
# 1  John   2014-01-01        Email
# 2  John   2014-05-01          Web
# 3  John   2014-20-01          Web
# 4  John   2014-20-04        Email
# 5  John   2014-01-03         <NA>
# 6  John   2014-01-25         <NA>
# 7  John   2015-05-27         <NA>
# 8   Tom   2014-01-01        Email
# 9   Tom   2014-05-01          Web
# 10  Tom   2014-20-01          Web
# 11  Tom   2014-20-04        Email
# 12  Tom   2014-01-03         <NA>
# 13  Tom   2014-01-25         <NA>
# 14  Tom   2015-05-27         <NA>
```

**Update**

As you are having memory issues, you can use `data.table` thusly

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
x_dt <- as.data.table(x)

merge(dt, x_dt, by=c("Name","ActivityDate"), all=T)
```

or, if you're not looking to `merge` you can `rbind` them, using `data.table`'s `rbindlist`

```
rbindlist(list(dt, x_dt), fill=TRUE)  ## fill sets the 'ActivityType' to NA in X
```

**Update 2**

To generate your `x` with 16000 uniqe names (I've used numbers here, but the principle is the same) and 30 dates

```
ActivityDates <- seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-01-31"), by=1)
Names <- seq(1,16000)

x <- data.frame(Names = rep(Names, length(ActivityDates)),
                           ActivityDates = rep(ActivityDates, length(Names)))
```

Comment: Beat me to it. This would be my first thought - make the two structures compatible, then merge.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. My date vector has 36 dates and I have 16000 unique names. How do I reorient your second step which is turning x into a dataframe?